# How should one best save a "documentation" of a directory tree?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-management, documentation

I have an old "music" directory tree with tons of files. Although it is being replaced by a new "music" directory tree (this time with FLACs instead of MP3s), I shall still like to keep a "documentation" of the previous directory tree, without actually storing the files.

How should I best do this?

I wish to know the file name, the path, the file size, the created/last modified/last accessed timestamps to be present in this text dump which hopefully just becomes a small .txt file. It is for future reference, but I don't need (nor can afford to store) the old files.

Windows 10.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You might find a lot of potential solutions using our search: https://superuser.com/search?q=list+directory+recursively+windows otherwise tell us what you have tried and how that fails to meet your criteria and we may be able to help you adjust it. There are many options in the linked duplicates.